# Can't use function return value in write context error message

Tags: php

While I was coding my online store I got this strange error message that I never saw it before!

*Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context on line 5*

Here's my code

```
    <?php 
                        if (isset($_GET['pro_id'])){
                            $product_id = $_GET['pro_id'];
                            $query = $con->query("SELECT * FROM viewcounter WHERE productcode='$product_id'"); 
                            if(mysqli_num_rows($query) = 0){
                                $insert_id = "insert into viewcounter (productcode) values ('$product_id')";
                                $insert_id = mysqli_query($con, $insert_id);
                                mysql_query("UPDATE viewcounter SET `views`=`views`+1 WHERE productcode='$product_id'")
                            }
                            $get_pro = "select * from products where product_id='$product_id'";
                            $run_pro = mysqli_query($con,$get_pro);
                            while($row_pro = mysqli_fetch_array($run_pro)){

                                $_SESSION['pro_id'] = $row_pro['product_id'];
                                $_SESSION['pro_cat'] = $row_pro['product_cat'];
                                $_SESSION['pro_brand'] = $row_pro['product_brand'];
                                $_SESSION['pro_title'] = $row_pro['product_title'];
                                $_SESSION['pro_price'] = $row_pro['product_price'];

                                echo '....';
";}}?>
```

And this is line 5 that I get the error message:

> if(mysqli_num_rows($query) = 0){

**Note: I skipped writing the code that connects my database here cause it's already alright!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if(mysqli_num_rows($query) = 0){`

That is assigning the value of the function to 0

For comparison, you need double or triple:

`if(mysqli_num_rows($query) == 0){`

[More info on PHP comparison operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)